# Joomla Module that shows article intro image, article title and alternative text of intro images as h2

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to build a module for Joomla! that I want to use as an header before the article that contains:

- artile title (as h1)
- a background as the article image intro
- the alternative text of the intro image (as h2)

I've tryed building the module starting from the "hello world" module [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module) and I'm editing this to my needs.

Now, I don't know how I can edit it to let it show what I need.

I've started from the background image creating this code in the default.php file without success.

```
<?php 
    // No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>


<div class="bg_header_article" style="background-image: url(&quot;/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>&quot;);"></div>
```

Any suggestion will be very usefull.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version and framework you're using, this can be accomplished out of the box.

What version of Joomla are you using?

[Gantry](http://gantry.org/) makes this easy, as you can have many module positions over the mainbody (article) position.